# How do I remove NAs and empty values by column names?

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

I have the following data frame:

```r
a <- c(3, 2, 1)
a_1 <- c(NA, "", NA)
b <- c(3, 4, 1)
b_1 <- c(3, NA, 4)
c <- c("", "", "")
c_1 <- c(5, 8, 9)
d <- c(6, 9, 10)
d_1 <- c("", "", "")
e <- c(NA, NA, NA)
e_1 <- c(NA, NA, NA)

df <- data.frame(a, a_1, b, b_1, c, c_1, 
                 d, d_1, e, e_1)
```

I want to remove columns that contain "_1" with only empty cells and NAs. However, I've only been able to find the code that removes ALL columns in the data frame that contain empty cells and NAs.

```r
empty_columns <- colSums(is.na(df) | 
        df == "") == nrow(df)
df[, !empty_columns]
df <- df[, colSums(is.na(df)) < nrow(df)]

  a b b_1 c_1  d
1 3 3   3   5  6
2 2 4  NA   8  9
3 1 1   4   9 10
```

But I want my resulting data frame to look like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(a, b, b_1, c, c_1, d, e)

  a b b_1 c c_1  d  e
1 3 3   3     5  6 NA
2 2 4  NA     8  9 NA
3 1 1   4     9 10 NA
```

Answer (score 4):

You could redefine `empty_columns` to check whether the column name contains `"_1"`...

```
empty_columns <- colSums(is.na(df) | df == "") == nrow(df) & grepl("_1", names(df))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`, `select` the columns that `ends_with` ("_1") and (`&`) those have all `NA` values (after converting the blanks (`""`) to `NA` with `na_if`, then remove those columns with `-`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    select(-(ends_with("_1") & where(~ all(is.na(na_if(as.character(.x), ""))))))
```

-output

```
  a b b_1 c c_1  d  e
1 3 3   3     5  6 NA
2 2 4  NA     8  9 NA
3 1 1   4     9 10 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Do some cleaning and `type.convert` columns first.

```
df[1:10] <- type.convert(df[1:10], as.is=TRUE)
```

Then it's just

```
df[!(colSums(is.na(df)) == nrow(df) & grepl('_1', names(df)))]
#   a b b_1  c c_1  d  e
# 1 3 3   3 NA   5  6 NA
# 2 2 4  NA NA   8  9 NA
# 3 1 1   4 NA   9 10 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the condition test for `""` and `NA`, using `grepl` to filter `colnames`.

```
df[, !(sapply(df, function(x) 
  (any(x == "", na.rm=T) & any(is.na(x))) | 
     all(x == "", na.rm=T) & !all(is.na(x))) & grepl("_1$", colnames(df)))]
  a b b_1 c c_1  d  e e_1
1 3 3   3     5  6 NA  NA
2 2 4  NA     8  9 NA  NA
3 1 1   4     9 10 NA  NA
```

This also works if there is a column with empty cells together with alphanumeric values.

Answer (score 0):

A couple more riffs on the `empty_columns` vector if you're like me and prefer iterating over columns. The tricky thing in the OP is having access to both the names and values of each column; you can do this by working across names and retrieving their columns, or with `purrr::imap_lgl` which is a shortcut for that.

```r
empty1 <- sapply(names(df), function(n) all(is.na(df[n]) | df[n] == "") & grepl("_1", n))
empty2 <- purrr::imap_lgl(df, function(col, id) all(is.na(col) | col == "") & grepl("_1", id))
```

You could also use regex in place of combining `is.na` and `== ""`.

```
empty3 <- purrr::imap_lgl(df, function(col, id) !any(grepl(".", col)) & grepl("_1", id))
```

All 3 get the same set of columns to drop.

```
df[!empty1]
#>   a b b_1 c c_1  d  e
#> 1 3 3   3     5  6 NA
#> 2 2 4  NA     8  9 NA
#> 3 1 1   4     9 10 NA
```